# Search directories and sub-directories for a partial file name and return the parent directory using Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking to search a mapped drive (F:) directory and sub-directory for a partial file name using Python3. If the partial file name is found, it returns only the parent directory file name.

The partial file is called 'Planning Toolbox' and can have characters before and after it.

I've created an example code that works but is incredibly inefficient.

```
import glob
import pathlib
import os

#Searches 2 folders deep
for subdir in glob.glob(r"F:\\*\*\*Planning Toolbox*"):
    subdir1 = (pathlib.Path(subdir).parent)
    subdir2 = (pathlib.Path(subdir1).parent)
    print(os.path.basename(subdir2))
    
#Searches 1 folder deep
for subdir in glob.glob(r"F:\\*\*Planning Toolbox*"):
    subdir1=(pathlib.Path(subdir).parent)
    print(os.path.basename(subdir1))
```

**Example File directories:-**

z:\001\Planning Toolbox V15.xls

z:\002\Archive\Old Planning Toolbox V14.pdf

z:\003\Live\New Planning Toolbox.xlsb

**Code should return:-**

001

002

003